# firefox downloads mp3 files without an extension

Tags: php, firefox, download

I am using a Download Class which i found here http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3220-PHP-Serve-files-for-download-with-resume-support.html to let ppl download mp3 files.

It works great in all browsers except Firefox (in all versions).

When i download an mp3 file using this class in firefox, it downloads files without .mp3 extension. what may cause this and how can i fix it ?

Comment: Are the files actually served as mp3 by the server?

Comment: yes they are served as mp3 files, but this download class has a rename function that i use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any code, my guess is that you're not sending the filename as an HTTP header:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $filename);
```

You should also be sending the correct MIME type:

```
header("Content-type: audio/mpeg3");
```

**EDIT:** Nevermind, thought I could not download the file at the OP's link and can now see that I was wrong. The script is clearly using these methods, just not sure if it's doing it properly.

Comment: Are you sure the filename is correctly set in the above header? This would cause the filenames to be extension-less.

Comment: oh man this solved the problem. Firefox doesnt make it if i rename it without extension. now it is fixed thanks..

Answer (score 8):

It seems that for Firefox to save the file with an extension you must surround the filename with quotes.

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check again filename. If file download have 1 character is spacebar (" ")
Example: "template import.xls". Firefox will be error that without extension in download.
You can function replace(" ", "") to fix this issue with asp.net:

HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + reportName.Replace(" ", ""));